# Node.js: mongoose.once('open') doesn't execute callback function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to save some json files inside my database using a custom function I've wrote. To achieve that I must connect to the database which I'm trying to do using this piece of code at the start of the function:

```
let url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/database";

(async () => {
    const directory = await fs.promises.readdir(__dirname + '/files')
    let database = await mongoose.createConnection(url, {useNewUrlParser:true, useUnifiedTopology:true});
    database.on('error', error => {
        throw console.log("Couldn't Connect To The Database");
    });
    database.once('open', function() {
        //Saving the data using Schema and save();
```

Weirdly enough, when executing `database.once('open', function())` the callback function isn't being called at all and the program just skips the whole saving part and gets right to the end of the function.

I've searched the web for a solution, and one solution suggested to use `mongoose.createConnection` instant of `mongoose.connect`.
As you can see it didn't really fixed the issue and the callback function is still not being called.

How can I fix it, and why it happens?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mongoose.createConnection` creates a connection instance and allows you to manage multiple db connections as the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#multiple_connections) states. In your case using [`connect()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#callback) should be sufficient (connect will create one default connection which is accessible under `mongoose.connection`).

By awaiting the `connect`-promise you don't actually need to listen for the `open` event, you can simply do:

```
...
await mongoose.connect(url, {useNewUrlParser:true, useUnifiedTopology:true});
mongoose.model('YourModel', YourModelSchema);
...
```

Comment: Oh so when I use ```await``` and wait for the connect promise I don't really need to wait for the open event because await makes sure that I'm connected?

Comment: That's my understanding, yes :)

Comment: mongoose.connect doesn't return a promise

Comment: @eol Apologies. Typescript tells me "await" has no effect on the expression "mongoose.connect". Switched it to an upvote, this just didn't solve my issue