# mongoose.connection.once('open') callback never firing

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongoose, next.js

I'm currently setting up a custom Node server with Next.js. The fact that I'm using Next.js shouldn't make any difference though.

In previous apps, I've always used `mongoose.connection.once('open', callback)` to start listening only when the database is open. This time, it's not working.

This is my connection configuration file:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { MONGO_URI } from '../constants'; // looks like 'mongodb://localhost/my-db' in development

mongoose
    .connect(MONGO_URI, () => {
        try {
            console.log(`Connected to ${MONGO_URI} with Mongoose.`);
        } catch (err) {
            throw err;
        }
    })

export default mongoose.connection;
```

I am importing this and using it in my main.ts file like so:

```
import express from 'express';
import next from 'next';

import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import logger from 'morgan';
import compression from 'compression';
import helmet from 'helmet';

import rateLimiter from './config/rateLimiter';
import db from './config/connection'; // This is the config file

dotenv.config();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || '8000';
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

const nxt = next({ dev });
const handle = nxt.getRequestHandler();

nxt.prepare().then(() => {
    const app = express();

    app.enable('trust proxy');

    app.use(logger('dev'));
    app.use(helmet());
    app.use(rateLimiter);
    app.use(compression());
    app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(express.json());

    db.once('open', () => {
        app.listen(PORT, () => {
            // This log never happens
            console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}.`);
        });
    });
});
```

It's extremely strange, because "`Connected to mongodb://localhost/my-db with Mongoose.`" **is in fact logged** when using the code above, but the express app simply never listens; however, when I remove the `app.listen` out of the `db.once` callback function, "`Listening on port 8000`" does of course get logged.

I'm stumped. *Why isn't the `'open'` event firing?* I've verified that mongo is working locally through the Mongo shell, and this same exact code was working when I had the folder which these files are in (`server`) separate from the Next.js app (when I was still debating which type of view layer to write).

The issue is not compatibility. I'm running Mongo 5.0.5, and Mongoose 6.2.5, which should be find according to [this](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/compatibility.html)

Please don't link to some other question. None of these have helped:

- [My mongo is compatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39428744/mongoose-never-connects-to-mongodb)
- [mongoose.connect doesn't return a promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62083671/node-js-mongoose-onceopen-doesnt-execute-callback-function)

Comment: I'm not 100% certain if this is the case, but do you think just because `nxt.prepare()` is async in nature by the time it resolves `.then()` and we enter the code block, it's too late? `db.once('open')` might already been fired but we couldn't capture it in time? Try moving the codeblock outside `nxt.prepare()` and see if it works?

Comment: @ShivamSood This solved the issue completely. Thank you, you were right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment from *@Shivam Sood* was correct. The `db.once('open')` was being called too late. Once `nxt.prepare` had happened, the db was already opened.

Here is the modified code:

```
import express from 'express';
import next from 'next';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';

import logger from 'morgan';
import compression from 'compression';
import helmet from 'helmet';

import rateLimiter from './config/rateLimiter';
import db from './config/connection';

dotenv.config();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || '8000';
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

const nxt = next({ dev });
const handle = nxt.getRequestHandler();

db.once('open', () => { // Listen for 'open' event before nxt.prepare, and before listening on PORT
    nxt.prepare().then(() => {
        const app = express();

        app.enable('trust proxy');

        app.use(logger('dev'));
        app.use(helmet());
        app.use(rateLimiter);
        app.use(compression());
        app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
        app.use(express.json());

        app.get('*', (req, res) => {
            return handle(req, res);
        });

        app.listen(PORT, () => {
            console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}.`);
        });
    });
});
```